# solr web interface can't be accessed over internet

Tags: indexing, ssh, solr, lucene, centos6

I'm Using SOlr on a vps server, the problem is that i can index and search over files using ssh.
But the problem when i access the web server using my browser, the browser displays this error

```
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

i thought it was a configuration problem so i tried wget using ssh like this

```
wget http://server_ip:8983/solr/
```

and it worked.

Using netstat command gave this

```
sudo netstat -nap | grep 8983
tcp        0      0 :::8983                     :::*   LISTEN      8540/java
```

Can someone help me
thanks

> I'm using Centos 6 and SOLR 5.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule is that you should not expose Solr to the general internet (so the wget is a bit worrying, unless the resulting file was something else than the user interface), as hasn't had a tradition for employing any sort of authentication or authorization (there is some support in recent versions).

The easy way is to use SSH forwarding:

```
ssh -L 8983:localhost:8983 user@host
```

That way you can just open `http://localhost:8983/solr` in your browser, and it will give you the Solr API just as you were located directly on your VPS. The connection will be encrypted, and nothing will be exposed to the internet.

Comment: thank you for your reply, it worked for me now. for wget command i just used when i was connected to the vps using ssh to test if the server is up and if there isn't a problem with the server, so i think it's secure.Thank you so much